# GLSL Check texture alpha between 2 vectors

Tags: opengl-es, textures, glsl, shader, shadow

I'm trying to learn how to make shaders, and a little while ago, I posted a question here : [GLSL Shader - Shadow between 2 textures on a plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313286/glsl-shader-shadow-between-2-textures-on-a-plane)

So, the answer gave me the right direction to take, but I have some trouble for checking if there is a fragment that is not transparent between the current fragment and the light position.

So here is the code :

Vertex Shader :

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;

varying vec2 uvVarying;
varying vec3 normalVarying;
varying vec3 posVarying;

uniform vec4 uvBounds0;

uniform mat4 agk_World;
uniform mat4 agk_ViewProj;
uniform mat3 agk_WorldNormal;

void main()
{
    vec4 pos = agk_World * vec4(position,1);
    gl_Position = agk_ViewProj * pos;
    vec3 norm = agk_WorldNormal * normal;
    posVarying = pos.xyz;
    normalVarying = norm;
    uvVarying = uv * uvBounds0.xy + uvBounds0.zw;
}
```

And the fragment shader :

```
#ifdef GL_ES
   #ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH   
      precision highp float;
   #else
      precision mediump float;
   #endif
#endif

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

varying vec2 uvVarying;
varying vec3 normalVarying;
varying vec3 posVarying;

uniform vec4 uvBounds0;
uniform vec2 playerPos;
uniform vec2 agk_resolution;
uniform vec4 agk_PLightPos;
uniform vec4 agk_PLightColor;
uniform vec4 agk_ObjColor;

void main (void)
{
    vec4 lightPos = agk_PLightPos;
    lightPos.x = playerPos.x;
    lightPos.y = -playerPos.y;

    vec3 dir = vec3(lightPos.x - posVarying.x, lightPos.y - posVarying.y, lightPos.z - posVarying.z);
    vec3 norm = normalize(normalVarying);
    float atten = dot(dir,dir);
    atten = clamp(lightPos.w/atten,0.0,1.0);
    float intensity = dot(normalize(dir),norm);
    intensity = clamp(intensity,0.0,1.0);
    vec3 lightColor = agk_PLightColor.rgb * intensity * atten;
    vec3 shadowColor = agk_PLightColor.rgb * 0;

    bool inTheShadow = false;

    if (intensity * atten > 0.05) {
        float distanceToLight = length(posVarying.xy - lightPos.xy);

        for (float i = distanceToLight; i > 0.0; i -= 0.1) {

            vec2 uvShadow = ???

            if (texture2D(texture0, uvShadow).a > 0) {
                inTheShadow = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (texture2D(texture0, uvVarying).a == 0) {
        if (inTheShadow == true) {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, uvVarying) * vec4(shadowColor, 1) * agk_ObjColor;
        }
        else {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, uvVarying) * vec4(lightColor, 1) * agk_ObjColor;
        }
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture0, uvVarying) * agk_ObjColor;
    }
}
```

So, this is the part where I have some troubles :

```
bool inTheShadow = false;

    if (intensity * atten > 0.05) {
        float distanceToLight = length(posVarying.xy - lightPos.xy);

        for (float i = distanceToLight; i > 0.0; i -= 0.1) {

            vec2 uvShadow = ???

            if (texture2D(texture0, uvShadow).a > 0) {
                inTheShadow = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I first check if I'm in the light radius with intensity * atten > 0.05

Then I get the distance from the current fragment to the light position.

And then, I make a for loop, to check each fragment between the current fragment and the light position. I tried some calculations to get the current fragment, but with no success.

So, any idea on how I can calculate the uvShadow in my loop ?

I hope I'm using the good variables too, cause in the last part of my code, where I use gl_FragColor, I'm using uvVarying to get the current fragment (If i'm not mistaken), but to get the light distance, I had to calculate the length between posVarying and lightPos and not between uvVarying and lightPos (I made a test, where the further I was from the light, the more red it became, and with posVarying, it made me a circle with gradient around my player (lightPos) but when I used uvVarying, the circle was only one color, and it was more or less red, when I was approaching my player to the center of the screen).

Thanks and best regards,

Max

Answer (score 1):

When you access a texture through `texture2D()` you use normalised coordinates. I.e. numbers that go from (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0). So you need to convert your world positions to this normalised space. So something like:

```
vec2 uvShadow = posVarying.xy + ((distanceToLight / 0.1) * i * (posVarying.xy - lightPos.xy));
// Take uvShadow from world space to view space, this is -1.0 to 1.0
uvShadow *= mat2(inverse(agk_View)); // This could be optimized if you are using orthographic projection
// Now take it to texture space
uvShadow += 0.5;
uvShadow *= 0.5;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand a bit more how it works :)

Sadly, seems like inverse function is not avalaible in OpenGL ES 2.0

And for the orthographic projection, I've looked a bit, and I found a little list with the constants I can use : (Under the first youtube videos) : http://forum.thegamecreators.com/?m=forum_view&t=201508&b=41

Maybe I can use agk_Ortho or agk_WorldOrtho, but I'm not too sure how I can use them... gonna take a look at this

Comment: Oops apologies invert() is es 3.0 only. If you are using orthographic projection you can do something like this assuming your texture covers the whole screen and doesn’t move:
uvShadow /= screenResolution;
uvShadow += 0.5;
uvShadow *= 0.5;